# Последовательное чтение из SQL

Tags: c#, события, sql

Всем привет!

Есть программа — один текстовый блок (`nameTextBlock`) и одна кнопка (`nextButton`) и `SQL`.

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, появлялось следующее значение строки из `SQL`?

Вот код, но он выводит только текущее значение из `SQL`:

```
private void GetSqlData()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=Jama-Dharma\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Cars;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    using (sqlConnection)
    {
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT c.Name FROM CarsCatalog c";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            nameTextBlock.Text = sqlReader.GetString(0);
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Всем заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `DataTableReader`, ну или сохраните ваши строки из `SqlDataReader` в какую-нибудь структуру данных (`List<string>`) и обходите его по кнопке.